# How to select 1st half part of pipe separated data

Tags: sql, oracle

Data in each record of a column named REQUEST_IP_ADDR is as below '10.247.32.44 | 10.247.32.44'. How do i select only 1st part that is  10.247.32.44 ?

--Below is the select query I am trying to run

`SELECT DISTINCT MSG_TYPE_CD, SRC, SRC_IP from MESSAGE_LOG order by MSG_TYPE_CD`;

--My table looks as below

```
MSG_TYPE_CD   SRC              SRC_IP
KB0192        ZOHO         10.247.32.44 | 10.247.32.44
KB0192        ZOHO         10.247.32.45 | 10.247.32.45
KB0192        ZOHO         127.0.0.1 | 10.240.20.137
KB0192        ZOHO         127.0.0.1 | 10.240.20.138
KB0196        GUPSHUP          10.240.20.59 | 10.10.1.19
```

I want select only 1st part of data which is before the pipe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the base string functions we can try:

```
SELECT
    SRC_IP,
    SUBSTR(SRC_IP, 1, INSTR(SRC_IP, '|') - 2) AS first_ip
FROM MESSAGE_LOG
ORDER BY
    MSG_TYPE_CD;
```

[image]

### Demo

The logic behind the first query is that we find the position of the pipe `|` using `INSTR`.  Then, we take the substring from the first character until *two* characters before the pipe (to leave out both the pipe and the space that precedes it).

A very slick answer using `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```
SELECT
    SRC_IP,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(SRC_IP, '^[^ |]+') AS first_ip
FROM MESSAGE_LOG
ORDER BY
    MSG_TYPE_CD;
```

### Demo

The regex pattern used here is:

```
^[^ |]+
```

This says to take any character from the start of the `SRC_IP` column which is *not* space *or* pipe `|`.  This means take the first IP address.

Comment: Thanks it worked, Can you please explain the working of this 1st solution in brief 
    SELECT
    SRC_IP,
    SUBSTR(SRC_IP, 1, INSTR(SRC_IP, '|') - 2) AS first_ip
FROM MESSAGE_LOG
ORDER BY
    MSG_TYPE_CD;